# Delphi 7 package editor counterpart

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10-seattle

In D7 there is a IDE pop-up for working with packages.  I'm not sure of its official title but according to Spy++ its Windows class name is TPackageEditorForm.

I find this pop-up very handy for working with packages, but it seems to have vanished from recent versions of Delphi (XE4 and up).  Has it, or is it tucked away somewhere out of sight?

This is it:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to add a screenshot. Nevertheless, you can try locating that form using http://rvelthuis.de/programs/ideexplorer.html

Comment: Doing a binary GREP on the D7 folder for "TPackageEditorForm", this is evidently contained in coreide70.bpl.  However, nothing in the Seattle bin folder contains that name, so unless it's been renamed, I think you may be out of luck.

Comment: @MartynA, Borkadero started to obfuscate strings in binaries since XE2up1 or such.

Comment: @FreeConsulting:  Oh, yet there is plenty of plain text in DelphiCoreIDE230.Bpl, including various "kibitz" items and "TAddRequiresDlg".  Anyway, thanks for the link to Rudy's package, I'm intrigued to have a play with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For newer versions of Delphi this is part of the [project manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Project_Manager). The actions from the toolbar buttons are now available from the context menu.